# How to disable/fix stack smashing detected error

Tags: 18.04, python

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 and Python 3.7 on my laptop and lab computer. Using PsychoPy, I designed a simple psychophysics experiment that runs without any error on my laptop but returns the following in the lab computer.

```
***stack smashing detected***: <unknown> terminated 
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Even though the same libraries, same version of Ubuntu and Python installed on both computers, could you tell me why this warning appears in one of them, and how can I fix this problem?

Thank you so much for your help :)

Comment: This question is better suited for **Stack Overflow**: https://stackoverflow.com/

Comment: I will post it there, thank you! https://stackoverflow.com/q/65463150/11841393